# Pull Information from Abaqus Input File

Tags: python, input, abaqus

I have a cae file with a bunch of different models and steps within the models and I would like a quick way of pulling the body heat flux loads from the input model in order to check them.

Is there a way to script something that goes through the input files, pulls the loads I'm looking for, and writes them into a .txt file for checking?

Below is the part of the input file that contains the information I want to capture.

```
** STEP: StepName
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Capsule   Type: Body heat flux
*Dflux, amplitude=Power
Capsule-1.Capsule, BF, 4685.4
** Name: Fuel   Type: Body heat flux
*Dflux
Fuel-1.Fuel, BF, 431422.
** Name: Rodlet   Type: Body heat flux
*Dflux, amplitude=Power
Rodlet-1.Rodlet, BF, 4659.5
** Name: Spacer   Type: Body heat flux
*Dflux, amplitude=Power
Spacer, BF, 7022.2
```

My initial question posted above was answered but I would like to add a little more to this question. I have multiple input files I would like this script to run through and would like the resultant output file to list inputfile, stepName, LoadName, and Load all on one line. That way I can copy and paste into Excel (Unless I can have it output into Excel then it would save me a step) and be able to sort through all the loads and know which file and step they belong too.

I tried to use the import glob and then pull information from all the input files in the directory but I'm at a loss for writing the information to the output file the way I want.

```
import re
import os
import glob

# Open output file for writing
outputFile = open('ATF_Loads.txt','w')

inputfileList = glob.glob('./*.inp')

for inputfile in inputfileList:

    with open(inputfile, 'r') as inpDeck:
        lines = inpDeck.read()

    lines=re.findall(r"^\*Dflux(|,\s*amplitude=[^,]*?)\n([^,]*?),\s*BF\s*,([^,]*?\n)",lines, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)

    for line in lines:
        outputFile.write(','.join(line))
```

Comment: I don't know whether there is something like an existing module or similar. However, could you please provide a snippet of that input file in order to get a clue about how you might process the data out of the file?

Comment: ** LOADS
    ** 
    ** Name: Capsule   Type: Body heat flux
    *Dflux, amplitude=Power
    Capsule-1.Capsule, BF, 4685.4
    ** Name: Fuel   Type: Body heat flux
    *Dflux
    Fuel-1.Fuel, BF, 431422.
    ** Name: Rodlet   Type: Body heat flux
    *Dflux, amplitude=Power
    Rodlet-1.Rodlet, BF, 4659.5
    ** Name: Spacer   Type: Body heat flux
    *Dflux, amplitude=Power
    Spacer, BF, 7022.2

Comment: The comment above is the part of the input file I want to extract the data from. the specific load I want to pull is fuel load (431422)

Comment: Please add that snippet to your question by editing your question since the formatting might become important. So please format the snippet in exactly the same way as the input file you have.

Comment: I added the snippet to my question.

Comment: the input file might not be the best way to do this. Perhaps you should think about accessing this information directly from the model database in the CAE file. you would need a python script to do this.

Comment: this is really straightforward in python. Show an attempt so folks know where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use regular expressions....

```
import re
import os

directory=r'C:\Users\Doug\Desktop'
fileName='sampleDeck'

file_fullPathName=os.path.join(directory, fileName + '.inp') 

with open(file_fullPathName, 'r') as inpDeck:
    lines = inpDeck.read()

lines=re.findall(r"^\*Dflux(|,\s*amplitude=[^,]*?)\n([^,]*?),\s*BF\s*,([^,]*?\n)",lines, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)

file_fullPathName=os.path.join(directory, fileName + '-out.txt') 
with open(file_fullPathName, "w") as outp:
    for line in lines:
        outp.write(','.join(line))  #Write text file
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. If you have time can you help me with a little addition to it. I have multiple input files that I would like this go through and there are many steps within this input file that it is pulling loads from. I would like it to organize the output file so that it shows the input file, step name, load name, load value. I'm going to edit my initial question to show how the different step names are called out.

Comment: If you have time I would also appreciate it if you could explain the lines.refindall command you have put in this script. That would help me out tremendously with being able to figure this stuff out myself or if you have a link to something that could help me understand it.

Comment: the re.findall command contains a regular expression to find matches in a chunk of text.  Regexs are almost a language in itself and there are some good websites which explain it. Use this to test them http://www.pyregex.com/.

Comment: To find each chunk of text related to the steps in your inp file, maybe you could use something like this:- re.findall(r"^\*\*STEP: ((.*?)\n.*\n(?=\*\*STEP)",lines, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL).   I have not tested this command so you would have to experiment a bit. Then create a for loop to cycle over each step to find the DFLUXs (using the other regex).  If you require any Abaqus consultancy services then we can provide them ... for a fee obviously :-)